# Minimizing borderless dialog issue

Tags: c++, qt, windows

I want to minimize the borderless modal dialog so it should stay in the taskbar. The problem is, the dialog minimized to the bottom of the screen:

**Screenshot:**

[image: 0_1510351504895_2017-11-11_000440.jpg]

**Code:**

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMinimized);
```

Also, this dialog is not the main window, so I think it should minimize them both when clicking minimize in the dialog and the issue is present in another non borderless modal dialog.

**Screenshot with minimized modal dialog with borders:**

[image: 0_1510400432885_FastStoneEditor1.jpg]

I use `Qt 5.9.2` on Windows 10.  How to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This happens if your dialog has a parent window, that is not currently visible. Try to create your dialog without a parent, i.e. `setParent(nullptr)`. (This also means you need to delete it yourself)

Comment: @Felix

Yes, I know, this issue only happens when parent has been set. When removing the parent it works well. I thought it was a bug in Qt?

Comment: It's intentional, as your dialog has no taskbar-entry of it's own. Thus, it get's minimized that way. It's per design on windows, and not a fault of Qt. On Linux, for example, it does minimize both windows at once. So for windows, this is the natural behaviour

Comment: @Felix
Ok. So shouldn't it also minimize both windows on `Windows OS` such as on `Linux`, or this window behavior is hard coded in the `Windows`? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is hardcoded into windows. Qt simply tells the OS to "minimize the window",  the OS then decides how to, and this is the result. If you want something different, you must code it yourself. (react on minimize event, hide the dialog and minimize the parent window and vice versa).

Comment: @Felix

Ok. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue has been fixed by removing parent or setting it to `nullptr`. Thanks to @Felix information, this is not a bug in `Qt`, it's default `Windows` behavior.